# How do I rotate text to 90 degrees while writing it in an svg file

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am creating a svg file and adding text to it using svgwrite, if the width of my text id is 0 I need it to be 90 degrees rotated

This is how I am doing it but I am still not able to get it rotated

```
if (int(text_list[i]['width']) == 0):
    g.add(dwg.text(string, insert=(left, top), transform="rotate(90)"))
```

Comment: I don't use Python but am confused... Why would the text width be zero? Is it because no text exists, and if yes, then why rotate empty text? Did you mean `If the width of my text id is 0, then I need the SVG itself to be 90 degrees rotated`?

Comment: the text width is 0 when the text present is vertical and got this  issue sorted

Answer (score 1):

```
 pcRotate = 'rotate(270,%s, %s)' % (left,top)
 g.add(dwg.text(string, insert=(left, top), transform= pcRotate)
```

on specifying the points around which I need to rotate the text, I am getting the desired results.